# $\cos(\sqrt{8} \phi_\sigma)$ term when bosonizing the Luttinger Hamiltonian

Tags: bosonization, tomonaga-luttinger-liquid

I am currently reading "Fermi liquids and Luttinger liquids" by Schulz (https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9807366). In page 27 it says the following:

[image]
[image]

My question is about how 
$$\frac{g_1}{(2\pi\alpha)^2} \int dx \cos(\sqrt 8 \phi_\sigma)$$
arises in (4.27), which is the bosonized form of (4.23). In this article, Bosonization convention is as follows:

$$\phi(x)=-\frac{i\pi}{L}\sum_{q\neq 0}\frac{1}{q} e^{-\alpha|q|/2-iqx} \left(\rho_+(q)+\rho_-(q) \right) - N\frac{\pi x}{L}$$
$$\theta(x)=\frac{i\pi}{L} \sum_{q\neq 0}\frac{1}{q} e^{-\alpha|q|/2-iqx} \left(\rho_+(q)-\rho_-(q) \right) +\frac{Jx}{L}$$
where $N=N_++N_-$ and $J=N_+-N_-$.

Please also note that the density fluctuation oeprator is defined as
$$\rho_r(q)=\sum_k c^\dagger_{k+q,r} c_{k,r}$$
in this article (and in this question), while commonly denoted as $\rho_r^\dagger(q)$ in other references.